# How to convert money from a currencies to another in Python

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am using Django to build a money transfer application and I would like a way to build a template tag in order to automatically exchange money from one currency to another using the OPENEXCHANGE URL. So, I referred to this link: https://django-money-rates.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html but it does not work and facing the issue in the attachment. How can I do it, please? Or is there another way to solve the problem?
For more information, I am using Django-3.1.7 and Python-3.8

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error in the picture is a ProgrammingError. You might want to run the migrations.

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```